# How do I calculate row sum in Bash without awk?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a question, how i can calculate row sum in Bash without awk, only f.e with loops, but if I have in input some pipes? It seems:

```
| 11 14 |
| 13  7 |
```

Thanks!

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code, and the (correct) expected result

Comment: Is the data in a file and are there only lines in the file that are structured in this way?

Comment: @markp_fuso, i tried it with awk and it worked, but i want to find the method without it and i have no idea.

Comment: @Cyrus, yes, data in a file and all numbers are structured in this way.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves. Please add your `awk` solution to your question.

Comment: A pure bash solution would only work for integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this entirely in bash without any additional utilities simply by reading each line into an array and then looping over each element in the array checking if the element is all digits and adding the number to the sum for the line. For example you could do:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

[ -z "$1" ] && {  ## validate 1 argument given for filename
  printf "error: filename required as argument.\n" >&2
  exit 1
}

file="$1"   ## assign argument to file

[ -s "$file" ] || {  ## validate file not empty
  printf "error file not found or empty.\n" >&2
  exit 1
}

while read -ra arr; do                               ## read line into arr
  sum=0                                              ## zero sum for line
  for i in ${arr[@]}; do                             ## loop each element
    [[ $i =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && sum=$((sum + $i))  ## all digits add to sum
  done
  echo "sum: $sum"                                   ## output sum
done < "$file"
```

(**note:** if negative numbers are possible, you can handle that with a simple check for zero or one `'-'` characters before all digits with `^-{0,1}[[:digit:]]+$` as the regex. To handle a leading `'+'` before the digits you would need to check for the leading `'+'` with `[[ ${i:0:1} = + ]]` and then remove it, `i=${i:1}`. Otherwise the addition would contain two `'+'` characters in sequence (e.g. `+ +`) and fail.)

You don't need to know the number of numeric elements beforehand, it simply loops over each whitespace separated word and checks if the word is comprised of all digits before adding it to the sum.

**Example Use/Output**

With the script in `sum.sh` and your example input in `file`, your output would be:

```
$ bash sum.sh file
sum: 25
sum: 20
```

Comment: Thank you for this ! I really want to find a solution in simple bash without any utilities.

Comment: The beauty here is it doesn't matter what your delimiter is. You can have `"foo | 2 |||bar 4 buz"` and you would still get `6`, and since it uses only bash built-in capabilities, it won't be bad from an efficiency standpoint either. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Say your input is in the file `/tmp/input.txt` (I added a decimal and negative number just because.)

```
$ cat /tmp/input.txt
| 11   -14 |
| 13.4   7 |
```

First, remove stuff that's not a number, a space, or a newline:

```
$ tr -sc '[- 0-9.]\n' ' ' < /tmp/input.txt 
 11 -14 
 13.4 7
```

Next, remove leading/trailing spaces:

```
$ tr -sc '[- 0-9.]\n' ' ' < /tmp/input.txt | sed 's/^ //;s/ $//'
11 -14
13.4 7
```

Now, replace the remaining spaces with a `+` operator:

```
$ tr -sc '[- 0-9.]\n' ' ' < /tmp/input.txt | sed 's/^ //;s/ $//;s/ /+/g'
11+-14
13.4+7
```

Finally, send all that into the calculator:

```
$ tr -sc '[- 0-9.]\n' ' ' < /tmp/input.txt | sed 's/^ //;s/ $//;s/ /+/g' | bc
-3
20.4
```

Comment: Of course this has little do with bash and everything to do with the usual unix utility programs.

Comment: I suggest to replace `[- 0-9.]` with `[ 0-9.-]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `dc`

```
tr -d '|' < file.txt | while read l; do echo $l + p | dc; done
```