# How to use bash command line to automate text-editing

Tags: bash

I assume I can use some commands like echo but not super sure. Either way, I am trying to find out how to automate one of my steps. The file (`file_1.txt`) that my script generates looks like this:

```
xxx , xx xx xxx

xx, xx , xx
 up, 70 , 23
 lw, 70 , 23

BZ,  22
LP,  30

SOLV,  7210
NA,  65
CL,  19

total xxx, xxxx
```

Later on, my script generates another file (`file_2.txt`) that looks like this:

```
[ system ]
; Name
XXX



    [ molecules ]
    ; Compound #mols
    PE
    PG
    BZ
    LP
    SOLV
    Na
    Cl
```

I want to find the way how to modify `file_2`, so to add numbers from `file_1` and particular points:

```
   [ system ]
    ; Name
    XXX
    
    
    
        [ molecules ]
        ; Compound #mols
        PE -->> add the sum of 70 (up) + 70 (lw) from file_1
        PG -->> add the sum of 23(up) + 23(lw) from file_1
        BZ -->> add 22
        LP -->> add 30
        SOLV -->> add 7210
        Na -->> add 65
        Cl -->> add 19
```

So effectively, grep numbers generated on specific column/row in `file_1` and add them to `file_2` in specific column/row. Or if there is any other easier way is also good.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If you "generate" `file_1` with the values `up, 70 , 23` and `lw, 70 , 23` why not simply store the values in arrays like `up=(70 23)` and `lw=(70, 23)` and then for `file_2` sum the values in the `up` and `lw` arrays?

Comment: Thanks, this is because it is an output of the software I use, I cannot modify it within the software, but can modify file_1 myself. But I thought, there can be a way  to do it with the current layout of the file_1.

Comment: Sure, you can always obtain the `up` line with `grep '^ *up.*$'`. Using command substitution you can store that in a variable, e.g. `upvar=$(grep '^ *up.*$' file_1)`. The remove the `','` with `upvar="${upvar//,/}"` and then remove the leading `up` with `upvar="${upvar//up/}"` and then add the numbers. Or you can just sum from the line as in [How do I calculate row sum in Bash without awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71544297/3422102)

Comment: Thanks, I can do that sure. However, my question was a bit different. Lets say "up" and "lw" do not exist in file_1 and file_2. I wanted to find out how I can use data from file_1 (from particular positions in the file) and to copy them into file_2 (into particular position in the file). Thanks

Comment: Then you keep a counter say `declare -i lineno=0` and then for every line read in your loop increment the number, e.g. `((lineno++))` Another approach with `grep` is to use the `-n` `--line-number` option to have `grep` output the line number where the match (say for `up`) was found. Then you can correlate that with `file_2`.